# openCV fincontours for float

Tags: c++, opencv

here is my code as you can see i'm using cv::Point and Vec4i

```
cv::Mat bwImage;
cv::cvtColor(dst,bwImage, CV_RGB2GRAY); 
cv::vector<cv::vector<cv::Point> > contours1;
cv::vector<cv::Vec4i> hierarchy2;
//% Get the borders of each object
//[B,~] = bwboundaries(bwImgLabeled,'noholes');
cv::findContours(bwImage,contours1,hierarchy2,CV_RETR_CCOMP, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);
```

since i need the precision is there a way to use this for cv::Point2f for example?
so findContours() will not return x=4 ,y=3 but will return x=4.312..., y=3.145....?

Comment: findContours uses binary image as input, not grayscale, which means that contours are exactly at discrete pixel locations! So you would have to create a binary image with subpixel precision which isnt possible except by supersampling your image before creating the binary image, extracting contours and subsampling afterwards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Input is an integer data (an image) and so the output is integer data as well (and this is the most precise answer).  In your case I would recommend you to start from providing different flags to findContours. Instead of CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE try using CV_CHAIN_APPROX_TC89_L1. This will perform some polygon simplification, i.e. it will 'smooth' contours a little in exchange for precision. Or you can perform simplification by using approxPolyDP after your call to findContours.